# How to store output from command to a path?

Tags: shell, command-line, dos

I am currently running a command and it is producing the compressed file. I need to store that zip file into c:\windows\abc.zip.  Does anyone know how to do that?

MY current command is something like this:
cd %path% cdx.exe

I have tried specifying the path after cdx.exe but it doesn't store in that path.
It is running the exe but storing on my desktop instead of c:\windows.

Hope it make sense.

Comment: What is the command you are running?  Is it a built in operating system command or a program you wrote?  Generally when a built in operating system command line program command needs input, you can just execute the program without any arguments and get a usage message which may help you figure out how to use it.

Comment: @NIck: No im not running the built in command, its the executable that we wrote and we are trying to store the output of that which is compressed file to a specific location. But it is for some reason not storing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` will output to a file (`>>` will append)

so try

```
cdx.exe > c:\windows\abc.zip
```

See the echo section here: [List of DOS Commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands#echo)

Comment: I had this same problem once, but I was using | instead.  I forgot I was on a machine that was neither *nix nor with Cygwin.

Comment: i tried this and it didn't work on some of the servers on which Im tryin to run abc.exe.some of them got successfull but other's failed